# UPDATE table and SET column based on condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement, pdo, conditional-statements

This is how my code looks now:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE product SET product_price_lowest = $adPrice WHERE product_id = $prodId");
$stmt->execute();
```

I want to **SET** product_price_lowest **TO** $adPrice only: 
 **IF** $adPrice **<** product_price_lowest

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then add that to `WHERE` clause as well like

```
WHERE product_id = $prodId
AND $adPrice < product_price_lowest
```

Comment: wow it worked, thanks a lot! I would never have thought of using "AND" as an IF statement.